# Route [product.status] not defined

Tags: laravel

Route [product.status] not defined. (View: /home/zubair/htdocs/et-solves/cms/resources/views/cms/pages/home/home.blade.php)

please see error https://flareapp.io/share/4m4qvWPM

**Route**

```
      Route::patch('/pages/product/status', 'HomeController@Status')->name('product.status');
```

Comment: Can you do `php artisan route:list` and see if your route is listed with the same name? It could be wrapped like `custom.product.status`

Comment: Please share your blade view

Answer (score 0):

I think so you are using prefix in your route group.

```
php artisan route:list --path=status
```

and check your route.